# Installation Problem with Basic MiKTeX 2.9.6753 Installer

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I am trying to install MiKTeX 2.9 using Basic MiKTeX 2.9.6753 Installer (64-bit) on a computer running Windows 10. Towards the end of the installation process, I receive the following error message:

> The operation could not be completed for the following reason:
>
> The executed process did not succeed.
>
> Details: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe",exitCode="1"

Does any one know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Note: The following is a log file in my computer. The path of this log file is "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\setup-2018-08-02-17-22.log".

```
initializing setup service...
starting installer...
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mik31294
visiting repository C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mik31294...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: b0545706fa706b64cc77217d98c169a9
going to install 10913 file(s) (215 package(s))
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from asymptote.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-spanish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex8bit.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex8bit-polish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from chktex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cweb.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cyrillic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from etex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from etex-pkg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontname.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ghostscript.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-cfg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-def.tar.lzma...
extracting files from gsftopk.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from knuth-lib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from knuth-local.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from makeindex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo-font.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mfware.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-asymptote-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-autosp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-axohelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bzip2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cairo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-chktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-console-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-curl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-devnag-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvisvgm-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-epstopdf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-etex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-expat-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freeglut-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fribidixetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gd-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphite2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gregorio-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-harfbuzz-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-int-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-jpeg-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-kpathsea-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lacheck-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-libressl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-log4cxx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua52-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua53-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lzma-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-m-tx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mkfntmap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpfr-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpmcli-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mspack-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pixman-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-png-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-popt-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-posix-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-potrace-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-qt5-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tdsutil-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex2xindy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ttf2pk2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ucrt-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-uriparser-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc140-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xindy-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zlib-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zzip-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from multirow.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ncntrsbk.cab...
extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from palatino.cab...
extracting files from pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from plain.tar.lzma...
extracting files from polyglossia.tar.lzma...
extracting files from poppler.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pslatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psnfss.cab...
extracting files from pstricks.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psutils.tar.lzma...
extracting files from rsfs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ruhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tex-ini-files.tar.lzma...
extracting files from texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from thumbpdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from times.cab...
extracting files from tools.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ttf2pk.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ukrhyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from unicode-data.tar.lzma...
extracting files from utopia.cab...
extracting files from xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xgreek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xindy.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xkeyval.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xltxtra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xunicode.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xypic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
extracting files from zerohyph.tar.lzma...
updating package definition directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
installed 3350 package definition files
visiting repository C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mik31294...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
initexmf "--common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin "--log-file=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:
Windows API error 87: 參數錯誤。


Info: path="C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\1756f6ade37d5f870f23c05a7f81e257.fndb"
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\MemoryMappedFile\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp
Line: 83

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
  source line: 177
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
```

Comment: Try out what works. Sometimes initexmf at the end only fails because of some fonts that fc-cache don't like and you can repair this later.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand what is fc-cache, could you explain more? Thank you very much.

Comment: I noticed that in the last days I got a similar error message when I updated MikTeX. I think I have narrowed that down to TeX-related processes running. In my case I had to close TeXworks so that `initexmf` could succeed.

Comment: @moewe no idea, I almost never use texworks. But I don't see why this should be the source of the problem here. Why should texworks be open at the end of the installation? Beside this: initexmf is used for a number of maintainance steps, so the question is which one fails: the update of the FNDB or the maps/font caches.

Comment: @moewe Well this sounds quite probable that texworks.exe can not be created when it is open ...

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu Do you have any log files in `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log` or similar that could give us a hint what is going wrong?

Comment: @moewe My MiKTeX is installed in the path C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9.  I don't know where the log files are. Could you please tell me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you install MikTeX so far that you can open the MikTeX Console? My MikTeX is also in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9`. Is there a `.log` in `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log`?

Comment: @moewe I don't know how to open the MiKTeX Console. And I do not have the directory "C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log" in my computer. There is a log file which locates in the following path: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\setup-2018-08-02-17-22.log", I will post it in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Uninstall MiKTeX 2.9.
2. Open the folder "C:\Program Files".
3. Delete the folder "MiKTeX 2.9".
4. Goto the website https://www.latex-project.org/.
5. Click "Get".
6. Click "proTeXt".
7. Click "download the self-extracting protext.exe file ".
8. Click "ProTeXt-3.1.9-121317.exe".
9. Save "ProTeXt-3.1.9-121317.exe" to your computer.
10. Execute "ProTeXt-3.1.9-121317.exe".
11. A folder named "ProTeXt" will be generated.
12. Enter the folder "ProTeXt".
13. Execute "Setup.exe".
14. Click the button "Install" on the right hand side of "MiKTeX".
15. Follow the instructions on the screen and complete the installation of MiKTeX.

Comment: I don't see "proTeX" option as listed at number 6th position in your answer.

Comment: @learner: The answer I posted was about five years ago. During this five years, the website may be modified.

Comment: It is alright, i understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. What worked for me was:

1. Remove the current installation from your computer location: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
2. Right click on the MiKTeX installer file and "Run as administrator"
3. Chose install for a single user instead of available for all.

Comment: Very often it is simply enouph to restart the installing process, sometimes Windows or the installer of MikTeX gets an "Hick-Up" and stops working. An restart solves this issue then (tested with a lot of students ...)

Comment: Unfortunately, reinstall did not work in my case.