# Getting older versions of Miktex. Can it be raplaced with Texlive?

Tags: miktex2.9, distributions, texlive-2017

I work with a journal that uses Latex format files that are intended for a 2016 Miktex distribution. The format files are incompatible with latest Miktex distributions. Recently I tried to install Miktex 2.9.6069 on a Windows 11 computer and was stuck at the error as described in [MiKTeX Installation Fails with "Executed process did not succeed"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329125/miktex-installation-fails-with-executed-process-did-not-succeed) and
[Installation Problem with Basic MiKTeX 2.9.6753 Installer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444267/installation-problem-with-basic-miktex-2-9-6753-installer)

Now I am willing to get a 2017 Miktex distribution, but did not manage to find one, except the source code: [Are previous releases of MiKTeX available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527952/are-previous-releases-of-miktex-available)

Are there any mirrors of the entire distributions of Miktex? Or maybe are there any time snapshots of CTAN?

If there are none, were the versions of Texlive compatible with the versions of Miktex? Which versions of Texlive may I try to use instead of Miktex 2017 versions?

Comment: sorry but without details about what is actually incompatible it is quite impossible to say if an older texlive would solve your problems. If your document uses new packages that require new formats installing an old system won't help. You could try on overleaf, it allows to compile with older systems. But generally: it is the job of your journal to enable compilation on a current tex system. They should force authors to install outdated tex systems.

Comment: I meant they should *not* force authors to install outdated tex system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The journal format is a derivative of revtex4n style. The authors are not forced to use the format, but the man, who works in the journal and formats the issues, is forced by the publisher. It is not me, but I wish to help the man.

Comment: well sorry but you are not helping him by trying to run an outdated tex system.  In the same way a journal has to update its other equipments like computers, laptops, OS or printer it should maintain its software. And that means it should invest some time to keep it up-to-date. And if a publisher want to use old software that should provide support for it and not rely on the community to handle this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately, the real world is not ideal. Many things that should be done are not done. I just wanted to ask a simple question: are there archives of old Miktex versions? May be there are some.